# Google Analytics SEO - PHP API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a PHP file which give's me google analytics data, such as pageviews, Top Pages, or Organic Data simple stuff.

Now I neet to get Stuff from the SEO Part.

For example: TOP 50 Search Keywords (with Impression and Clicks)

I can't find any help in the API how to get these values.

this is a example of my api call:

```
$params = array(
    'dimensions' => array('date', 'pagePath', 'pageTitle'),
    'metrics' => array('sessions', 'pageviews'),
    'sort' => '-ga:sessions',
    'filters' => null,
    'startdate' => $startdate,
    'enddate' => $enddate,
    'startindex' => null,
    'limit' => 25,
    'mapping' => array('pagepath' => 'pagepath', 'pagetitle' => 'pagetitle', 'sessions' => 'visits', 'pageviews' => 'pageviews'),
);

$results = $this->service->data_ga->get($this->profile, $params['startdate'], $params['enddate'], $metrics, $optParams);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search engine optimization data shown in Google Analytics actually comes from Google Search Console (Webmaster Tools) and is available from the Google Search Console API.
https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You would need to update the [Dimensions and Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) of your query. The [traffic dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_keyword) should be of help.

Below is a simplified query which gets the number of impressions and clicks for various sources and keyword combinations:

```
$optParams = array(
  'dimensions' => 'ga:source,ga:keyword',
  'sort' => '-ga:impressions,ga:source',
  'filters' => 'ga:medium==organic',
  'max-results' => '25');

$metrics = 'ga:impressions,ga:adClicks';
$results = $this->service->data_ga->get(
    'ga:XXXX',
    'today',
    '7daysAgo',
    $metrics,
    $optParams);
```

Your code must have some mapping that it does from the values in `$param` field to the actual dimensions and metric names. I would also encourage you to play around with the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to get a field of what queries are possible.

Comment: Okay Got this, one more question, the avgPosition of the search is not of this API. Google gives me no hint how to get this. I found adSlot that just dont seem right.

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working how i want it to be.

Comment: I need the pagepath + impression + clicks  + avgposition. Just like the webpage shows it.  When i try using the dimensions with pagePath  and session it gives me following error : "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together."